# dynamodb condition expression with multiple values

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I using following query expression to get Campaign for a particular id

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Campaign> expression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Campaign>()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("#id = :val1")
    .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributeNames)
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);

PaginatedQueryList<Campaign> campaigns = dynamoDBMapper.query(Campaign.class, expression);
```

Let's say, i want to get Campaigns for list of ids. So instead of calling above query multiple time with different ids, can i just make one call to dynamodb with list of ids?

Comment: Check for BatchGetItems

Comment: Hi Harshal, thanks for the suggestion. After going through documentation, BatchGetItems can fulfill my usecase explained in the question. But as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749560/whats-the-difference-between-batchgetitem-and-query-in-dynamodb) batchGetItem doesn't support filter expression and we will need filter for our future usecase

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?