# AWS Dynamodb BatchGet with FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve list of items from dynamodb table based on some filters. In Filters, I have my list of hash keys (records having one of that hash key should be returned) and few more filters on the record, for example a "status" field having value as "approved". So if the item is having hash key from my list AND status field value is "approved" it should be returned. 
How can I do that ? 
I cannot use QUERY because according to my understanding it expects only 1 hash key value. 
I cannot use BatchGet because it does not accept filter expression.

Answer (score 4):

You can user `BatchGet` to get the items, and filter them by your own function.

[Doc: Working with Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

> A Query operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before the filter expression is evaluated.

As you see, use filter expression cannot help you to retrieve more data, which also cannot save your read capacity(money). So I think it make no difference to filter locally or server-side.

If you want dynamo to do the heavy lifting filtering the data for you, then you can try `"multi-query"` instead of `BatchGet`.

Here is some relevant references, [What's the difference between BatchGetItem and Query in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749560/whats-the-difference-between-batchgetitem-and-query-in-dynamodb/30772172)